# Как открыть страницу другого сайта в приложении,построенном на ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть страница в приложении с формой для заполнения. При нажатии отправки данных, проверяется сторонний сервис(если пользователь дал разрешение использовать аккаунт зарегестрированный там).Если проверка проходит неудачно,нужно вместо текущей страницы загрузить страницу этого сайта. Как это можно сделать средствами `React`? Предполагаю, что как-то через рутер. Поугглив нашел [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022308/redirect-to-a-page-programmatically-in-react-router-2). Но в этом вопросе редирект происходит внутри реакт приложения, мне же нужно перейти в текущем окне на другой сайт...Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Кажется что это задача не совсем для реакта. Первое что приходит на ум - window.location.replace(...), Реакт-роутер нужен чисто для history API-реквестов внутри приложения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if('проверка') {
  'удачное событие';
} else {
 location.href="https://google.ru";
}
```

`react-router` здесь не нужен.